# spring data neo4j - using server extension through repository

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I read about the server extensions available in `neo4j` in server mode. I was wondering if it is possible to somehow annotate repository method to use this extension insted of allowing to create query based on method name or `@Query` annotation?

If not, is there easy way to invoke `REST` interface methods using `Neo4jTemplate`?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible right now, it would be cool though, feel free to raise a JIRA issue that describes your suggestion in more detail. Perhaps Spring-Data-REST Clients allow such a thing.

Comment: Ok, I will raise the JIRA issue then.